# Update Statement with Where Combobox

Tags: vba, ms-access, combobox, where-clause, sql-update

What I am trying to accomplish is update multiple records in a table that meets criteria that is stored in a combobox. The field that I am trying to update set to Null (also a combobox stored as text, key field hiding).

I have been able to get the where statement working with a checkbox

[Main].[TAD] is a combobox stored as text, primary key field hiding.
[TADSlctRtrn] is a unbound combobox stored as text, primary key field hiding on a unbound form.
both fields are linked to the same data.

Code that I have tried (code works without WHERE statement)

```
CurrentDb.Execute "UPDATE [Main] SET [TAD] = Null WHERE [TAD] = " & Me.TADSlctRtrn

CurrentDb.Execute "UPDATE [Main] SET [TAD]= Null" & "WHERE [TAD] = Me.TADSlctRtrn.Value"

CurrentDb.Execute "UPDATE [Main] SET [TAD]= Null" & "WHERE [TAD] = Me.TADSlctRtrn.text"

CurrentDb.Execute "UPDATE Main SET TAD = Null" & "WHERE TAD = Me.TADSlctRtrn.Value"

Run-time error 3075:

syntax error (missing operator) in query expression '[TAD] = jackson'

Run-time error 3075:

syntax error (missing operator) in query expression 'NullWhere TAD = ME.TADSlctRtrn.Value'
```

Answer (score 1):

Solved

Code that worked

```
CurrentDb.Execute "UPDATE [Main] SET [TAD] = Null WHERE [TAD] = '" & Me.TADSlctRtrn & "'"
```